# Why my try-exception-finally cant work properly

Tags: python, error-handling

it's homework from udemy,my solution cant work,here is the question:

**Write a function that asks for an integer and prints the square of it. Use a while loop with a try, except, else block to account for incorrect inputs.**
here is my solution:

```
def ask():
    while True:
        try:
            user_input = int(input('give me int energe:'))
            squ = user_input**2
            print('boom! show you my power:'+squ)
        except:
            print('lack of int energe')
            continue
        else:
            print('Gotcha')
            break
        finally:
            print('boooooom')
        
    pass
```

if I input str, the exception works well but even I input an int also show the same result as str,why this happens??
[image: my error screenshot]

here is the correctly solution:

```
def ask():
    
    while True:
        try:
            n = int(input('Input an integer: '))
        except:
            print('An error occurred! Please try again!')
            continue
        else:
            break
            
        
    print('Thank you, your number squared is: ',n**2)
```

I am not sure why my attempt cant going well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `print` statement is throwing an exception.  You cannot append a string and an int using `+`.  Either use

```
print('boom! show you my power:' + str(squ))
```

or

```
print('boom! show you my power:', squ)
```

In general untyped except statements are a really bad idea.  If you had instead written `except ValueError:`, catching only the error thrown by trying to convert a string to an int using the `int()` function, you would have immediately seen the problem.

Comment: Thank you sooo much:)

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the error lies in:

```py
print('boom! show you my power:'+squ)
```

`squ` is type `int`, and you're using the `+` operator where the left side has a string and the right side has an int. Either change the int to a string, or use the `,` character. Either of these would work:

```py
print('boom! show you my power:', squ)

print('boom! show you my power:' + str(squ))
```